# I am having issues specifying using "this" with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, gsap

What I want to be able to do is click on a div and scale that particular div only using the TweenMax and JQuery libraries. Currently the example below is updating all the flex-items divs.

HTML:

```
<div class="main-content">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex-items" onclick="mouseOver()"></div>
            <div class="flex-items" onclick="mouseOver()"></div>
            <div class="flex-items" onclick="mouseOver()"></div>
            <div class="flex-items" onclick="mouseOver()"></div>
            <div class="flex-items" onclick="mouseOver()"></div>
            <div class="flex-items" onclick="mouseOver()"></div>
            <div class="flex-items" onclick="mouseOver()"></div>
            <div class="flex-items" onclick="mouseOver()"></div>
            <div class="flex-items" onclick="mouseOver()"></div>
            <div class="flex-items" onclick="mouseOver()"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function mouseOver(){
    var flexItem = $(".flex-items");
    TweenLite.to(flexItem, 1.5, {width: 500, height: 500, ease:Power2.easeOut});
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use the `onclick` attribute.  If you're using jQuery, you should use `$('.flex-items').on('click', function(){ ... });` or closer to your current code `$('.flex-items').on('click', mouseOver);`

Comment: or only `.click(function()`... https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: click() will suffice in this situation, on() is usefull when you need to remove the function from the element with off()

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting all the items every time the function runs.

Also, you should use jquery's `.on()` with an anonymous callback function instead of the `onclick` attribute with an unnecessary named function

Try something like this

```js
$('.flex-items').on('click', function() {
  // This is the problem, you are selecting all flex-items everytime
  // var flexItem = $(".flex-items");

  // This should work
  var flexItem = $(this);
  TweenLite.to(flexItem, 1.5, {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    ease: Power2.easeOut
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
    <div class="flex-items"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was faster mwuhahaha

Comment: You were faster than him by exactly 17 seconds. :P

Comment: To be fair, I spent time explaining what the problem was

Comment: Next time post first the essentials and then edit it afterwards to add the explanation to win :D

Answer (score 1):

```
function mouseOver(){
    var flexItem = $(this);
    TweenLite.to(flexItem, 1.5, {width: 500, height: 500, ease:Power2.easeOut});
}
```

You mean like this?